Sort Multiple Columns Independently from Each Other
I have multiple columns in a spreadsheet with headers that I will be adding to each over time but at different amounts. The columns will be independent from one another and growing at different rates.
I know how to sort all by currentregion, but that seemed to only allow sorting based off one header. For simplicity's sake, how would you alphabetically sort 2 columns simultaneously next to each other?
Tried something like this but it won't run:
Sub Alphabatize()
' Alphabatize Macro
Dim LastRowA As Long
Dim LastRowB As Long
'Determine Last Row
    LastRowA = Range("A1" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowB = Range("B1" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'Sort
     With Range("A1")
        .SetRange Range("A1:LastRowA")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    With Range("B1")
        .SetRange Range("B1:LastRowB")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub


Right off I can tell you the reason .SetRange Range("A1:LastRowA") isn't working is because you set LastRowA as a variable but you use it as a string literal when attempting to reference it. Should be .SetRange Range("A1:" & LastRowA). Also wouldn't be a bad idea to qualify the range to the worksheet at a minimum but that's just me.

You are missing the sort method With Range("B1") should be With Range("B1").Sort

Please, try the next way. But simultaneity concept is a little different. They are sorted in the same piece of code, but consecutively... :
Sub sortTwoIndependentColumns()
 With ActiveWorkbook 'use here the workbook you need
    With ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Columns("A:A") 'columns to be sorted
            .cells.Sort key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, header:=xlYes
        End With
        With .Columns("B:B")
            .cells.Sort key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, header:=xlYes
        End With
    End With
 End With
End Sub

